# Consecutive Declarations on Line Must be Separated By ";"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
func createButtonWithTitle(title: String) -&gt; UIButton {

  let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
  button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
  button.sizeToFit()
  button.titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
  button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
  button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
  button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)

  button.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

  return button
}
```

Throwing error on line number 1 before `UIButton`.
How do I fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean?! just change `-&t;` to `->` and you'll be good to go! It's just a typo! I'm guessing you have copied the text from web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace this `-&gt;` with `->`, which is what it is supposed to be.

***Addendum:***

You haven't shown the subsequent errors you're still getting; however, I decided to test your code and managed to fix these for you in Xcode 7.1 (in Swift 2).

Please see the changes made in comments.

```
func createButtonWithTitle(title: String) -> UIButton 
{
    //buttonWithType is no longer available; please change it to
    //UIButton(type:)
    let button = UIButton(type: .System) as UIButton

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()

    //unwrap titleLabel using "!"
    button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

    //translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is a property and
    //it is no longer a member function
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: "didTapButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}
```

Comment: okay how can i connect with you please ? because i'm still getting error after changing it to ->